# Trying to output data which has been input by user

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm having issues trying to output data which a user has inputted into a form.. It's a 2 block form, I'm just trying to save the data into 2 variables and then echo the variables. But I don't understand where I'm going wrong. Any help appreciated.

```
    <?php

echo $problem = ""; 


if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="submit"){

    if(!empty($_POST['eWeight']) && $_POST['eWeight']!=''){       
$eWeight = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['eWeight']));
    } else {
       $problem .= "Please enter a weight. <br/>";
}

if(!empty($_POST['gym']) && $_POST['gym']!=''){       
$gym = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['gym']));
    } else {
       $problem .= "Please enter time at gym. <br/>";
}



echo $eWeight, $gym;





}


?>
<?php
if($conn){
     echo "connected";
}

echo $problem;
echo $eWeight;

?>
  <form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" name="contact_weight">

 <label for="eWeight">Enter Weight: </label> <input type="number" id="eWeight" name="eWeight" placeholder="88" required/>


 <label for="gym">Enter Time at Gym: </label> <input type="number" id="gym" name="gym" placeholder="60" required/>

<button class="submit" type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your `isset($_POST['submit'])` will always return `false`, because your submit button doesn't have a name attribute. `<button class="submit" type="submit" name="submit">Submit Form</button>` should work, though.

Comment: You need to set method="post" and action="some page" attributes in form element.

Comment: Hi, I've added the name attribute but I still can't get an output when I'm trying to echo the variable through the isset

Comment: Where are you defining the variables $conn and $eweight? In this code they look undefined? Your echo has to do when a $conn is established, can we see that code?

Comment: $conn works, it's the connection to the database which has been defined in an external page. I've defined $eWeight at the top but given it no value. I'm trying to add a value via form input then output, but I receive no output

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<?php

echo $problem = ""; 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if(!empty($_POST['eWeight']) && $_POST['eWeight']!=''){       
    $eWeight = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['eWeight']));
} else {
    $problem .= "Please enter a weight. <br/>";
}

if(!empty($_POST['gym']) && $_POST['gym']!=''){       
    $gym = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['gym']));
} else {
    $problem .= "Please enter time at gym. <br/>";
}

echo $eWeight, $gym;
}

if($conn){
  echo "connected";
}

echo $problem;
echo $eWeight;

?>

<form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" name="contact_weight" action="" method="post">

    <label for="eWeight">Enter Weight: </label> <input type="number" id="eWeight" name="eWeight" placeholder="88" required/>        

    <label for="gym">Enter Time at Gym: </label> <input type="number" id="gym" name="gym" placeholder="60" required/>

    <button name="submit" class="submit" type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't just dump a bunch of code, explain what was wrong with the original and how you fixed it.

Comment: I've tried this, still can't manage to get a value into the variable via the form and then out put.. I'm starting to think the 'mysqli_real..' might be the issue.

Comment: yeah, might be, actually i tried with commenting `escape string` code and replaced it with the post value and worked fine. So, might be `escape string` is only thing not working properly.

Comment: I've removed the escape string and kept it plain and simple with the POST_.. But still no output! It's really frustrating, anybody have an idea?